# Oracle PL/SQL: Stop the procedure batch when encountering exception

Tags: oracle, plsql

Suppose I have 3 procedures running together, which insert record A,B,C respectively:

exec P1
exec P2
exec P3

Assume P2 will throw exception, while P1 and  P3 are okay.

My expected flow is :
Run P1 -> A inserted -> Run P2 -> Encounter exception -> Rollback -> Stop from running P3

The ultimate expected outcome is nothing changed.

I have defined exception and exception handling for P2, which will rollback. However, I cannot stop it from running P3, i.e. C is still inserted.

Google tells me there is `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK`, but I discovered that it could not work on self-defined exception. In other words, it only works on Oracle official exception, such as:

**ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 10:
PLS-00201: identifier 'COLUMN_DOES_NOT_EXIST' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored**

To achieve the expected outcome,  my thoughts are(but I don't know how to do it!):

1. Add exception handling to P2, such that it can stop P3 from running.
2. Run `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK` before running the procedures. (but it can only work on Oracle official exception instead of my defined exception)

I do appreciate your help  if you can fix either one.

The following is my code for your reference:

```
PROCEDURE INSERT(
    INPUT IN TABLE.INPUT%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
) AS
BEGIN
    IF INPUT NOT IN ('A','B','C') THEN
      RAISE invalid_input;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (...);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN invalid_input THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Invalid input' );
      rollback;             ---How to stop next procedure from running?
    WHEN others THEN
      rollback;
END;
```

When I run
exec INSERT(A)
exec INSERT(Y)
exec INSERT(C),
the outcome is that C is inserted, while I want nothing changed.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you're executing. Thanks.

Comment: maybe I am not understanding but couldn't the three procedures just be in a package? so in the package you run proc 1, followed by proc 2, followed by proc3.  If something goes south and you haven't put a commit in their anywhere everything auto-magically gets rolled back for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added one line to your procedure (and changed a bit to run test example):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ins(P_INPUT IN t.INPUT%TYPE DEFAULT NULL) AS

 invalid_input exception;
BEGIN
    IF P_INPUT NOT IN ('A','B','C') THEN
      RAISE invalid_input;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO t (INPUT) VALUES (P_INPUT);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN invalid_input THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Invalid input' );
      rollback;             ---How to stop next procedure from running?
      raise;     -- re-raise exception added
    WHEN others THEN
      rollback;
END;
```

Table:

```
create table t (input varchar2(1));
```

Test script:

```
SQL> declare
  total_rows number;
begin
  ins('A');
  ins('D');
  ins('C');
exception
  when others then
    select count(*) into total_rows from t;
    dbms_output.put_line('Error ocured. Total rows in table T: ' || total_rows);
end;
/
Invalid input
Error ocured. Total rows in table T: 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

As I understand, it is your desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added 'raise' to my exception handling but it does not work as expected.

Comment: @MolderNg I changed my code. Check, is it what you need?

Comment: Thank you! Actually I used raise_application_error to solve my second problem, but your solution is what I exactly wanted at the beginning. It works well, thanks again!